# Sum the rows by selecting range of column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

Hi I am trying to make a new dataframe by calculating the sum of the rows of original dataframe by ranges of years

The original df is:

| Year | ID | count_1 | count_2 | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019 | A | 1 | 1 | A00 |
| 2020 | A | 0 | 1 | A00 |
| 2019 | B | 1 | 0 | B00 |
| 2018 | A | 1 | 1 | A00 |
| 2021 | B | 1 | 0 | B00 |
| 2022 | B | 0 | 0 | B00 |

I want to sum the count of 'count_1' and 'count_2' by 'ID' and Year and still keep 'code'
So, the final output should look like below:

| ID | count_1_sum_18_19 | count_2_sum_18_19 | count_1_sum_20_21_22 | count_2_sum_20_21_22 | code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 0 | 2 | 1 | A00 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | B00 |

Thank you.

Comment: This data doesn't make much sense mate... Having columns with identical names, grouped this way is typically not considered to be a "well structured data". Can you explain what is what you're trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I understand your point, the reason there are same ID in a column is because it is differentiated by 'Year'. Just think of this as transaction data where each row has same customers but different time or dates

Answer (score 0):

Is something like that any useful to you? I am struggling a bit to understand exactly the data model / structure ..

```
>>> df.melt(['ID','code','Year'], var_name='count').groupby(['ID','code','Year']).sum().unstack('Year').fillna(0)

        value
Year     2018 2019 2020 2021 2022
ID code
A  A00    2.0  2.0  1.0  0.0  0.0
B  B00    0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it via `pd.cut` and `pivot`:

```
bins = [0, 2019, 2022]

k = (
    df.assign(
        bin=pd.cut(df.Year, bins=bins, labels=['18_19', '20_21_22']))
    .pivot_table(
        index=['ID'],
        columns='bin',
        values=['count_1', 'count_2'],
        aggfunc=sum)
)
k.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in k.columns]
```

OUTPUT:

```
    count_1_18_19  count_1_20_21_22  count_2_18_19  count_2_20_21_22
ID                                                                  
A               2                 0              2                 1
B               1                 1              0                 0
```

**`Complete code`**:

```
d = {'Year': {0: 2019, 1: 2020, 2: 2019, 3: 2018, 4: 2021, 5: 2022}, 'ID': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'A', 4: 'B', 5: 'B'}, 'count_1': {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0}, 'count_2': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 0}, 'code': {0: 'A00', 1: 'A00', 2: 'B00', 3: 'A00', 4: 'B00', 5: 'B00'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

bins = [0, 2019, 2022]

k = (
    df.assign(
        bin=pd.cut(df.Year, bins=bins, labels=['18_19', '20_21_22']))
    .pivot_table(
        index=['ID'],
        columns='bin',
        values=['count_1', 'count_2'],
        aggfunc=sum)
)
k.columns = ['_'.join(col) for col in k.columns]
```

Comment: This makes sense, but... the problem is that he has identical column names (count_1_sum_18_19 count_1_sum_18_19 count_1_sum_20_21_22 count_1_sum_20_21_22) which I don't quite understand how does he want/expect to get grouped..

Comment: That was a typo according to me. Column names are not the same. @DanailPetrov. OP needs to clarify further

Comment: can I ask one more question?

Comment: Ive applied the code but keep getting this error
'<' not supportedd between instances of 'int' and 'str'
do you happen to know why this is occuring?

Comment: @Python123new in which line you're getting this error?. Plus, I've added the complete code.